# Regression: Training Test Split - held out test?

Tags: python, tensorflow, train-test-split

i split my data into training and test samples (70/30) for regression-forecasting based problem (MLP, LSTM, etc.).

Within the code:

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32, 
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=0, shuffle=False)
```

I put my **test** data as the validation set and did couple weeks worth of predictions. So i did not hold back the test data...

But now that i think about it, i guess it was wrong to put the test data into the fit function, or was it ok?

Comment: In theory you should split the training data again, into train and validation sets. Then, the test set should be used only _once_.

Comment: I have 539 rows in my data.
I will held back 10% for the test data (last 53 rows).
Then i will split the remaining data in a ratio of 70/30 to a test and a train dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NEVER EVER! use your testing that as part of training or validation. The test set should only be used for inference after training. So yes it's wrong to use your test data in the fit function, it should only be in `model.predict(y_test)`

Comment: yeah, makes sense :(

Thank you
I will start over!

Comment: please upvote if you are satisfied with the answer, it helps a lot

Comment: i changed it so that i splitted my Data into Train (340 Samples), Val (145) and Test (54). 
The fitted curve looks good, i get a googd mape score of 4% but my r-squard is negativ. 

Is it also ok, if i do not use a val-data and test it immediately (for use in my thesis)?